# Wordpress Multisite theme upload

Tags: wordpress

I am new in wordpress. I am trying to build multisite using single wordpress installation. In that how I can change theme of every site? Please give me some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Once you setup your multisite, you will see a new menu option where all your sites are listed. You can change such settings from there. Here is a screenshot

http://codex.wordpress.org/images/7/78/network-admin-link.png

To change themes you can check Themes section here 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration